# [aiofiles & asyncio dont write logs in file.txt

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram

The question is as to why it does not write certain logs to the file, errors are not shown.
Bot for tg on aiogram.

logs.py:

```
import aiofiles
import asyncio

async def writelog(user_id: int, log: str):
    return 
    async with aiofiles.open('assets/recently.txt', mode='w') as f:
        await f.write(f'{user_id}:{log}\n')

async def readlogs():
    return ''
    async with aiofiles.open('assets/recently.txt', mode='r') as f:
        text = await f.read()
    return text
```

The code for writing a log to a file from script:

```
await writelog(message.from_user.id, 'turn off notifications')
```

help with the code, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning from the functions, that's why it is not working.

Change the code to this

```py
import aiofiles
import asyncio

async def writelog(user_id: int, log: str):
    async with aiofiles.open('assets/recently.txt', mode='w') as f:
        await f.write(f'{user_id}:{log}\n')

async def readlogs():
    async with aiofiles.open('assets/recently.txt', mode='r') as f:
        text = await f.read()
    return text
```

If you don't have complexity in your code and if you are calling the functions in a right manner, then this must work.

To append logs, you must have 2 functions in place. One is to create a new file, another is to add lines on that file

```py
import aiofiles
import asyncio

async def createlogfile(user_id: int, log: str):
    async with aiofiles.open('assets/recently.txt', mode='w') as f:
        pass

async def writelog(user_id: int, log: str):
    async with aiofiles.open('assets/recently.txt', mode='a') as f:
        await f.write(f'{user_id}:{log}\n')

async def readlogs():
    async with aiofiles.open('assets/recently.txt', mode='r') as f:
        text = await f.read()
    return text
```

Createlogfile will create an empty log file and writelog will append newlines. Notice that the mode on writelog is`a`, which is append.

Comment: Another question, how to write a lot of actions to a file?

Comment: Can you explain what you referred by actions here?

Comment: no, this work, the record is kept every time in the first line...my question was - how do I continue the list?

Comment: I edited the answer and added the append section. You can check it

Comment: Thank you very much! your help is priceless, the best

Comment: Please upvote to make it more reachable